# echo session first name and last initial and full name

Tags: php, echo, sessionid

```
$_SESSION['first']=$result['first_name'];
$_SESSION['last']=$result['last_name'];
```

Need to echo out
first name and last name. And First name and last initial. that should look like:

Joe S.
Joe Smith

```
<option value="Realname"><?php echo $_SESSION['first'] ?></option>
```

I know this one only gets the first name. Not sure how to from here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried concantinating the variables using the `.` operator like `$_SESSION['first'].' '.$_SESSION['last']`

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="Realname"><?php echo $_SESSION['first'].$_SESSION['last'] ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function to get only the first character of the last name.

```
<option value="Realname"><?php echo $_SESSION['first'] . ' ' 
    . substr($_SESSION['last'], 0, 1) . '.' ?></option>
```

To show the full last name, simply concatenate the full variable.

```
<option value="Realname"><?php echo $_SESSION['first'] . ' ' 
    . $_SESSION['last'] ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Joe S.

Strings can be seen as **Char Arrays**. To get first character, web can use [0] (I'm pretty sure is much faster than the substr method).

```
<option value="Realname"><?php echo $_SESSION['first'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['last'][0] . '.'  ?></option>
```

2) Joe Smith

Use just **concatenate** operator.

```
<option value="Realname"><?php echo $_SESSION['first'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['last']  ?></option>
```